# Filtering values and copying data to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm looking to filter and move data from a main excel spreadsheet (sheet 1) into a new sheet (sheet 2) but all the advice I've found so far relates to filtering just one column of data and I want to move two. I also need to filter by a wildcard.

I've attached an image of my sheet 1, and what I'd ideally want to create in sheet 2.

Column A is date; column B is animal type; column C is weight.

I need to filter by a wildcard to find all the 'horses' in column B and then move the date, the animal type and the weight to spreadsheet 2.

I've managed to do the first part using

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B2,"*horse*"),Sheet1!B2,"")
```

but I'm stuck on the 2nd part of removing all the blank rows.

[Animal weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIvh5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub horses()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D100") '<== range containing data, headers included
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="*Horse"
    If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > .Columns.Count Then
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") '<== copying form cell "A1" of "Sheet2"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

adapt commented lines as per you needs

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function to get your result. You can parse any content to this function to get the result in Sheet2.

```
Private Function filtercontent(content As String) As String
    Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        If InStr(Cells(i, 2), content) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

or

```
Private Function filtercontent(content As String) As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        If InStr(Cells(i, 2), content) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

for example if you want the apply the filter for Horse then

```
Sub testing()
    filtercontent ("Horse")
End Sub
```